# apache spark - Inserting a dataframe as nested struct into other dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have the two dataframes created in spark

xml_df:

```
root
|-- _defaultedgetype: string (nullable = true)
|-- _mode: string (nullable = true)
```

and nodes_df:

```
root
 |-- nodes: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _label: string (nullable = true)
```

the xml_df will have always just one rows, as described as follows:

```
+----------------+------+
|_defaultedgetype| _mode|
+----------------+------+
|      undirected|static|
+----------------+------+
```

and the nodes_df data:

```
+-----+
|nodes|
+-----+
|[1,1]|
|[2,2]|
|[3,3]|
|[4,4]|
|[5,5]|
+-----+
```

I used the struct function in the nodes_df to put _id and _label inside the struct. Based on that, i would like to add a third column in the xml_df dataframe that contains the struct created in the nodes_df dataframe.
I tried to use a join function creating a literal id for each entry in nodes_df, but the column result as null.

Any light please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why my join was not working.

I needed to use aggregation for the nodes column, so then i was able to proper join the dataframes.

i created an id for the xml_df:

```
StructType(List(StructField("id",IntegerType, true),
                    StructField("_defaultedgetype",StringType, true),
                    StructField("_mode",StringType, true)))
```

and the same for the nodes_df

```
val nodes_schema = StructType(List(
        StructField("id",IntegerType, true),
        StructField("_id",StringType, true),
        StructField("_label",StringType, true)
        ))
```

i used the id 666 for both of then and used aggregation in the nodes_df

```
nodes_df = nodes_df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_set("nodes").as("node"))
```

and joined with xml_df:

```
xml_df = xml_df.join(nodes_df, Seq("id"),"right").drop("id")
```

the result is:

```
+----------------+------+--------------------+
|_defaultedgetype| _mode|                node|
+----------------+------+--------------------+
|      undirected|static|[[2,2], [3,3], [5...|
+----------------+------+--------------------+

root
 |-- _defaultedgetype: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _mode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- node: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _label: string (nullable = true)
```